# How to group certain fields of a class in one JSON and the other fields in another JSON

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I am using `jackson` to create `JSON` for my `REST` web service.

I have a class like below -

Foo Class -

```
   public class Foo extends Bar {
       private String id;
       private String name;
       private List<Test> testing;
   }
```

Bar Class -

```
   public class Bar {
      private String username;
   }
```

Test Class -

```
   public class Test {
      private String id;
      private String desc;
   }
```

The desired JSON output that I intend to have is as follows -

```
{
  "username" : "ABC",
  "data": {
           "id" : "123".
           "name" : "XYZ"
           }
  "testing" : [
                {
                  "id" : "test1",
                  "desc" : "description1"
                }
              ]
}
```

I tried all possible `annotations` and want to avoid creating a `Wrapper` class just for creating `JSON` in a certain format.
The class `Foo` is populated from the database using getters and setters.

Note - I am new to `jackson`

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want JSON that looks like what you posted and you need to create classes that will produce that?

Comment: I want to get the JSON output from the Foo class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it is easier to create a wrapper class instead of trying any other way to hack into the problem.
You can create a wrapper class to take the input, like:

```
public class WrapperClasss {

private String val;

public String getVal() {
    return val;
}
public void setVall(String val) {
    this.val = val;
}   
}
```

Then your code can go like this:

```
@Path("/path")
public class SomeWebService {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseObject getRegister(WrapperClasss wrapperClasss) {
        MainClass classs = new MainClass();
        ResponseObject responseObject = classs.someMethod(wrapperClasss.getVal());
        return responseObject;
    }

}
```

That is it. The `Response Object` here is just an object that will contain your output. That will be converted to JSON by Jackson.

```
public class ResponseObject{
    private String username;
    Data data;
    private List<Test> testing;

    //respective getter and setters
}
```